# Firebase implementation using pod file and getting Symbol(s) not found error in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am implementing firebase into my Xcode project using pods for push notification. I have followed all the instructions that are given on firebase.com for iOS.

```
        $ cd your-project directory
        $ pod init
        $ pod 'Firebase/Core'
        $ pod install
        $ open your-project.xcworkspace 
        Upload APNs certificate successfully
```

Link followed: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

After doing all the things I'm getting the error:

> Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot the "@import Firebase" (without the quotation marks) statement on your delegate.

Another important thing: to use the push notifications with Firebase, you have to add pod 'Firebase/Messaging' to your Podfile.

I hope it helps

Comment: I have done what you said.But fortunately I resolve the issue as in other linker flag value is not set properly.